# Why does Idris 2 fail to resolve constraints with function composition in this trivial example?

Tags: typechecking, idris, function-composition

I have encountered a problem with some code I am trying to write in Idris 2. I would like to resolve this issue, but more importantly, I wish to understand it more deeply and develop some skills in diagnosing such issues in general.

I have distilled the problem to the following relatively trivial example:

```
data D : Nat -> Type where
  V : (n : Nat) -> D n

d : (n : Nat) -> D n
d n = V n

f : D n -> String
f (V n) = show n

t : Nat -> String
t = f . d
```

The definition of `t` fails type checking with the following output:

```
Error: While processing right hand side of t. Can't solve constraint between: ?n [no locals in scope] and n.

Test:11:9--11:10
 07 | f : D n -> String
 08 | f (V n) = show n
 09 | 
 10 | t : Nat -> String
 11 | t = f . d
```

Some experimentation has revealed that the following alternative definitions for `t` also fail type checking:

```
t : Nat -> String
t n = (f . d) n
```

```
t : Nat -> String
t = \n => (f . d) n
```

While these alternatives type check successfully:

```
t : Nat -> String
t n = f (d n)
```

```
t : Nat -> String
t = \n => f (d n)
```

I am endeavouring to learn Idris (for the second time), and so while I could move on with the definitions which don't involve function composition, I would like to improve my understanding.

It seems to me that the definitions which pass type checking are simply syntactic alternatives with identical semantics and behaviour, and I don't understand why the function composition definitions fail type checking. I would also like to understand the particular error message the type checker reports, so that I can deepen my understanding and resolve similar type checking errors in the future.

I have a few broad questions:

- **How should I interpret the error** reported by the type checker in this example, and **how can I gather more information** about the `?n` and `n` types mentioned? I particularly welcome any advice or tips on how to go about understanding and resolving such an error (teach a man to fish, as the saying goes).
- **Why do the definitions involving function composition fail type checking?**
- **What is the best solution for this example?** Should I just use a definition which does not involve function composition? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let look at the types involved

```
Prelude.. : (b   -> c     ) -> (a        -> b   ) -> a -> c
f :          D n -> String
d :                             (n : Nat) -> D n
```

The problem is:

```
(a        -> b   )
(n : Nat) -> D n
```

cannot be unified because `(a -> b)` does not allow the value of the argument to determine the type of return value.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had assumed it should work, since though `b` is not `a`, it will still accept a function for which they are the same. My understanding coming from other functional languages is that `a -> b` applies no constraint to `b` in relation to `a` - they can be different types or the same type. So I expected it to accept any function. But I guess dependent types introduces a different set of possibilities.

Comment: Does this then imply that function composition and actually many other common concepts, such as `map` of `Functor`, are constrained to functions which do not have dependent return types?

Comment: @label17 your understanding is correct

Comment: Yes, I receive the same error when trying to define: `s : List String` as
`s = map f $ map d [1 .. 3]`. And further, when trying to define a function `m : Vect k Nat -> Vect k (D ?)` the problem reveals itself more clearly. It is not possible to define the value on which the type `D` depends in the resulting type, since it would be different for each element of the vector, which does not satisfy the type.

Comment: @label17 SO isn't suited to longer conversations. Can we continue this in the Idris Discord https://discord.gg/UX68fDs2jc ?

Comment: Thank you very much @michaelmesser for the explanation! Yes, I will jump onto the Discord.